# Get user security attributes on AIX 5

Tags: c, aix

Is there a way to get user security attibutes (like password expiration warning time, maximum age for password and so on) by AIX 5 API?

Answer (score 1):

Look at the getuserpw() API for password information, and getuserattr() for the more generic user information.

Note that you will have to be a member of the appropriate group(s) in order to access the files in /etc/security.